# Sharepoint Framework for Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-hosted-app, spfx

I know the new SPFx will be released for Sharepoint 2016 sometime in the year 2017. But are there any plans to also bring this for Sharepoint 2013?

Are there any possibilities/hacks to add a Sharepoint app created with SPFx in the Sharepoint 2013 app catalog?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft has said that SPFx was really designed for SharePoint Online, but it will be available in SharePoint 2016--but nothing on SharePoint 2013. Here is an article that explains (in the comments)...

https://blogs.office.com/2016/05/04/the-sharepoint-framework-an-open-and-connected-platform/

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/known-issues-and-common-questions

Excerpt:

> Will SharePoint Framework be available in on-premises?
>
> Date - 28th of
>   April
>
> We are working getting SharePoint Framework released to SharePoint
>   2016 during 2017 calendar year. We do not have other public dates
>   currently available

Short answer, probably not. But no one really knows for sure, because it hasn't been addressed.

To your second question -- no, it's a completely different animal, like trying to push a square block in a round hole.

Answer (score 3):

Like Mike already mentioned.

- Current plans are to release SPFx to SP2016 - we do not have currently plans for SP2013
- You can use modern web stack development tooling with SP2013, but that's not the same as using SPFx

If you are looking into using modern web stack tooling with SP2013 for future proofing your customizations, we'd recommend to have a look on following webcast. It's a simplistic starting point, but does push you to right direction - https://dev.office.com/blogs/using-modern-web-stack-with-sharepoint-on-premises-deployments