# How to implement SPFX - SharePoint frame Work inside SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-framework

I have tried SPFX inside SPO, But is there a way to add the look and feel of SPFX inside Sharepoint 2013 mainly for the usage of Mobile compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SharePoint Framework** is only available for **SharePoint 2016**  and **SharePoint Online**, so it won't support **SharePoint 2013 on-premise**.

A similiar thread for your reference:

[Sharepoint Framework for Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215715/sharepoint-framework-for-sharepoint-2013)